# How to avoid usage of include_once

Tags: php, optimization, include

In PHP, let's say I have three classes:

```
database.php
item.php
user.php
```

Both classes item and user have the statement `include("database.php");` in order  to connect to the database and perform queries.

Say, I have a page where I want to show user info and item info. I would have to type

```
include("item.php");
include("user.php");
```

But this, of course, gives me an error because I include the database class twice. I know I could use `include_once("database.php");` in the item and user classes, but I've read read in various threads it's better not to use the _once-versions of include and require.

What is the best practice to avoid the usage of "_once" in PHP code when you need to include a database class on multiple places?

Comment: Can you reference these articles that say not to use _once?  I have always used them where needed and have never had a problem.  You could as an alternative do the same as you do in C++ header files and define some sort of variable, if its not defined already then do everything in your connection class, if it is defined already you know youve already included.

Comment: use `include_one` and `require_once` normally or even better, use autoloader

Comment: Ignore that advice, it’s wrong. *Do* use `require_once` (or, as Marko said, even better to configure an autoloader).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would have thought the best solution would be not to do `include` calls in your main code at all. Instead, autoload your files, so they are only included when they are needed.

```
spl_autoload_register(function ($class) {
    include 'classes/' . $class . '.php';
});
```

Now, if your code gets to something like `new database();` and the `database` class isn't loaded, this function will include `classes/database.php`. If the class is used again in future, the class will already be loaded, so the autoloader won't be used again.

See the documentation for [`spl_autoload_register`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-register.php) for more information.

Comment: That's pretty neat! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can include database in main script, from where other scripts are being included, however usage of `include_once` and `require_once` is normal and there is no any critical performance issue.

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure about your basic fear of *_once, but ...

```
include("database.php");
include("item.php");
include("user.php");
```

One way is to call it as you need and remove the include line from the classes.

Comment: This is extremely bad if as a unit item needs access to the database, it shouldn't rely on other classes including its dependencies, it should include its own dependencies.

Comment: What if its a different database depending on the situation? Now you have to open up all the classes.  Moot point anyhow, the db should be injected into the class that depends upon it -- but I didn't bother going into that in my reply either ...